# Fetch returns empty response but Network tab shows data

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Using this simple snippet:

```
fetch("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCAL3JXZSzSm8AlZyD3nQdBA", { mode: "no-cors" })
  .then(r => {
    console.debug(r);
    r.text().then(t => console.debug(t)).catch(console.error);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

I receive an empty response (`null` body, empty `url`, `status` of zero, `ok` is `false`), however when I go to the Network tab, I can see the data in the Response tab within it. I expect `fetch` response to give me the same.

What gives? I've tried adding `credentials: "include"` but it didn't make a difference and shouldn't, this resource should be accessible without it.

Comment: it's because youtube doesn't want you to fetch resources like that, they do not send CORS headers, so you can't get the resource into a browser directly - if you remove `{mode: 'no-cors'}` you'll see the CORS error - read what mode no-cors **actually** means [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode)

Comment: Why does the network request go through, though? It is an RSS feed, shouldn't I be able to just `GET` it?

Comment: the request goes through because it's the response headers that control CORS - so you have to get a response to know if CORS is enabled for the site. You can see the response body in the console because there's no security issues with seeing the response body in the console, as you can just open the page anyway, right. The fact that it's an RSS feed is irrelevant - youtube clearly don't want browsers that are viewing other sites to directly access their RSS resources. You need to "proxy" the request on **your** server

Comment: Aha. Okay. Can you answerize the comment for me to accept it?

Comment: no need, I think it's been covered plenty of times on SO

Comment: @JaromandaX can u please explain the proxying part in a bit more detail? I am stuck on the exact same thing right now. Maybe you can take a look at this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67942609/express-response-json-returns-data-in-network-tab-but-is-undefined-in-code-i

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will answerize because it helped me :)

> the request goes through because it's the response headers that control CORS - so you have to get a response to know if CORS is enabled for the site.
>
> **You can see the response body in the console because there's no security issues with seeing the response body in the console, as you can just open the page anyway, right.**
>
> The fact that it's an RSS feed is irrelevant - youtube clearly don't
> want browsers that are viewing other sites to directly access their
> RSS resources. You need to "proxy" the request on your server